# How can i create a searchbar in pyqt

Tags: python, mysql, user-interface, pyqt

I'm making a glossary of Keywords. I've considered putting all the terms in a big label. But that's not efficient or nice to look at. How can i make a form with a search-bar which displays all the terms but allows you using the search-bar to filter it depending what you write in the line edit? Any other ideas of how i can do the glossary would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`QCompleter`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcompleter.html) can do the auto complete part - here's a simple working example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

model = QtGui.QStringListModel()
model.setStringList(['some', 'words', 'in', 'my', 'dictionary'])

completer = QtGui.QCompleter()
completer.setModel(model)

lineedit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
lineedit.setCompleter(completer)
lineedit.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You could maybe add a list widget that also shows a list of all available words. You can also use `QComboBox` with the auto complete functionality.

Comment: thanks for your answer the auto complete is very useful, the thing with qtlistwidget is that you cannot copy and paste which wouldnt be good for a glossary

Comment: No worries. I suppose the thing to do would be to use the lineEdit as a search bar and have a list or tree view that is filtered by the lineEdit input.